# BigQuery Issue with Select when using AS

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

We love BigQuery it is amazing and we use it a lot but we have an issue with the Select statement, for some reason if you create a Select based on Variables you defined it does not work, but when you use the full code of the variables it does

The error I get is the following -

```
Error: (L5:47): Expression 'RequestsPerSession' is not present in the GROUP BY list
```

off course we do not want to aggregate based on this variable - there for it is no in the GROUP BY section.

This does not work

```
SELECT
  ch,
  COUNT(Distinct(AC_SessionID),15000000) As UniqueSessions,
  COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL)) AS Requests,
  ROUND(Requests/UniqueSessions,1) AS RequestsPerSession
```

This does work

```
SELECT
  ch,
  COUNT(Distinct(AC_SessionID),15000000) As UniqueSessions,
  COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL)) AS Requests,
  ROUND(COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL))/UniqueSessions,1) AS RequestsPerSession
```

Any Ideas on how to fix it?

Also is there a way to create a variable within the select function for calculation purposes but not have it show up in the final results?

Comment: Put some of the logic in a derived table.

Comment: You should use a subquery with a derived table. It gets too complicated for you, and later you won't find where the data error comes from. Don't be afraid using subqueries, they are good, and no performance hit at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Any Ideas on how to fix it?

The [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby) clause allows you to group rows that have the same values for a given field or set of fields so that you can compute aggregations of related fields. Thus, in SELECT list you can have either fields that you group by or [aggregations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions)
Accepting above - your first example fails as expected and second one works as expected.

So, nothing to fix really!

> Is there a way to create a variable within the select function for
>   calculation purposes but not have it show up in the final results?

You can use [subquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from_subqueries) for this
For example assuming your original query is:

```
SELECT
  ch,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(AC_SessionID),15000000) AS UniqueSessions,
  COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL)) AS Requests,
  ROUND(COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL))/UniqueSessions,1) AS RequestsPerSession
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ch
```

With subquery it can look as something like below:

```
SELECT
  ch,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(AC_SessionID),15000000) AS UniqueSessions,
  COUNT(request) AS Requests,
  ROUND(COUNT(request)/COUNT(DISTINCT(AC_SessionID),15000000),1) AS RequestsPerSession
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ch, 
    AC_SessionID, 
    IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL) AS request
  FROM YourTable
)
GROUP BY ch
```

which can be further "transformed" to

```
SELECT 
  ch,
  UniqueSessions,
  Requests,
  ROUND(Requests/UniqueSessions, 1) AS RequestsPerSession
FROM (
  SELECT
    ch,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(AC_SessionID),15000000) AS UniqueSessions,
    COUNT(request) AS Requests,
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      ch, 
      AC_SessionID, 
      IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL) AS request
    FROM YourTable
  )
  GROUP BY ch
)
```

At to which extend to go with such "optimization" is upto personal preferences, I think

> As for the subquery option, doesn't it increase the volume of data
>   that we run on as it is double the data (almost double) - we have a
>   lot of data so costs does start to an issue

Within the same query you can have multiple subqueries against the same table(s) and you will be charged only as you do it ones! So far, this is how billing works. So you shouldn't worry about it. BigQuery is smart enough to optimize actual data usage, so performance also shouldn't be of much concern I think

Comment: Why is my first version not considered and aggregations, while the second one is.

Comment: second version has COUNT() which is considered as aggregation function while first version does not! see more in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions - it is linked in my answer, but pasting it here again

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but just to clarify, the variable Requests in my first version is and Aggregation, does that not make the second line that uses it Aggregation as well, it just seems not efficient having to write the code again when there is a variable that already hosts that value.   As for the subquery option, correct me if I am wrong but doesn't it increase the volume of data that we run on as it is double the data (almost double) - we have a lot of data so costs does start to an issue.

Comment: you are wrong! it is important for you to understand  - from query prospective Requests is just a field and the fact that it was clculated using aggregations in inner selects/subselects doesn't make it qualified as aggregation function.

Comment: i looked again  - so actually you produce Requests in outter select and you expect it to be visible right away in same select. This is not a case. Aliases are not available that way. You need to write respective code again OR you should use subselects as it is in answer. As of cost - see update in answer and also I updated ny answer with more "details"

Comment: Dear Mikhail, I think you are wrong, Aliases are visible right away, we use it all the time (see example of UniqueSessions in my original code). There is a specific issue here is explicitly telling big query that this is an Aggregated field - can this be done?

Comment: 1. i realized i overstated about aliases - actually i am using them within the same statement quite frequently, even in my answers here, but this was mostly with analytical functions and not with group by. 2 i have mimic your scenario with very simple group by example and i see your point now - is this expected behavior of BigQuery - I really don't know.

Comment: this answer got too bushy so I posted new answer on your very original question. I still believe that my first answer addresses some of your questions too

Answer (score 0):

> Any Ideas on how to fix it?

try below "workaround"

```
SELECT
  ch,
  COUNT(Distinct(AC_SessionID),15000000) As UniqueSessions,
  COUNT(IF(Action CONTAINS "request_data",1,NULL)) AS Requests,
  ROUND(Requests/UniqueSessions,1) * MAX(1) AS RequestsPerSession
```

I realized that looks like engine needs some hint to understand that this particular field (RequestsPerSession) is not for grouping by but rather aggregation.

Below is how I "tested"

```
SELECT id, 
  COUNT(a) AS b,
  SUM(a) AS c,
  COUNT(a)/SUM(a) AS k1,
  b/SUM(a) AS k2,
  COUNT(a)/c AS k3,
  MAX(1) * (b/c) AS k4
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS a),
(SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS a),
(SELECT 1 AS id, 3 AS a),
(SELECT 1 AS id, 4 AS a),
(SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS a),
(SELECT 2 AS id, 2 AS a),
(SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS a),
GROUP BY id
```